How to export module name to functions launched as a process?
I have two functions myFunc() and myOtherFunc() defined in two different files: generic.py and no_choice.py with two different implementations. I import them as follows into main.py:
main.py:
if __name__=="__main__":
    config = input()
    if config=="generic":
        import generic as myfile
    else:
        import no_choice as myfile

Two functions use this import. fun1() and fun2() defined in main.py.
main.py:
def fun1():
  # Do some processing
  myfile.myFunc()

def fun2():
  # Do some processing
  myfile.myOtherFunc()

Then, I use multiprocessing to launch these two functions as parallel processes, as follows:
main.py -> within if __name__=="__main__"::
fun1task = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun1)
fun2task = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun2)
fun1task.start()
fun2task.start()

I get the error: NameError: name myfile is not defined from the line myfile.myFunc() from main.py -> fun1().
How do I enable these two functions defined outside the if __name__=="__main__": block to use the name myfile?

Does it work if you use target=myfile.myFunc instead of target=fun1?

Hi @mkrieger1 , That may not be useful, as I need to retain fun1() and fun2() as I plan to expand their functionality with some preprocessing before they make the call to myfile.myFunc(). I have updated the question to indicate that.

But does it solve the NameError?

yes, it solves the NameError, but doesn't solve the question on how I can get the functions to recognize the name, or use myfile.

Pass your functions as arguments.
Change your func1 and func2 signatures to:
def fun1(func):
  # Do some processing
  func()

def fun2(func):
  # Do some processing
  func()

And then pass func as an argument:
fun1task = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun1, args=(myfile.myFunc))
fun2task = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun2, args=(myfile.myOtherFunc))

